# Not set focus when come back screen manager with kivy and python

Tags: python, kivy, focus, screen

I want set the focus in textinput. at the begining the focus set correctly but when i go to the next screen and come back to initial screen the focus dont set correctly.

This is a app with a rfid lector, I want to read a code and select enter or exit

**main.py**

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0') # replace with your current kivy version !


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager,self).__init__()


class Menu1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Menu1, self).__init__()


class Menu2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Menu2, self).__init__()


Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class Fichaje(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Fichaje().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import WipeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.WipeTransition

<MyScreenManager>:  
    #transition: WipeTransition()
    Menu1:
        id: menu1       
    Menu2:
        id: menu2


<Menu1>:
    name: "screen1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: input1
            size_hint_y: .1
            multiline: False
            focus: True
            on_text_validate:                
                root.manager.current = "screen2"

        BoxLayout:  


<Menu2>:
    name: "screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Entrada"          
            on_press:          
                root.manager.current = "screen1"

        Button:
            text:"Salida"
            on_press:       
                root.manager.current = "screen1"
```

No error messages but the focus is not in the right site,
Thanks

**I change the code to simplify the error**

Comment: This example contains much more than two screens with textinputs. Is that necessary? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: label and clocklabel is necessary, in the second screen there are two buttons, when press a botton come back the first screen. 
The other things that you can see in the python code will be usefull in the future.
Thanksyou!

Comment: No problem, just a hint. If you want quick answers, then boil your example to only where your issue is. And still being runable.

Comment: def LimpiaInput(self):
        self.ids.TxtCodigo.text = ""
        self.ids.TxtCodigo.focus = True <=======Not working


If you see code that is not necesary you can erase it, I´m lost in this moment.

thanks!!

Comment: It's really easy in kivy. Forget the mess you are working with for a moment. Create a new example that reproduces the issue. We don't need to know size hints, images and labels and if you run sqllite3 or...... Should only take two screens layouts with a couple of textinputs. Then we don't need to use 10 minutes figuring out what comes first. Well now I spent 10 minutes explaining this anyways :D

Comment: Sorry but before to do a question, i did many changes and i didn't find the solution. And now i havent solutions

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: @el3ien I change the code, can you help me?

Comment: Yes no problem. That is much cleaner thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, there is not an attempt to change the focus. But I assume this was tried but it lost focus again.
The reason the text input looses focus again, is because it gets focused before the mouse or tap is released. The `on_press` method, is followed by `on_release` where the text input looses focus again.
To fix this you can just set the focus in the `on_release` method instead.

The quickest is to only add one line of code to the kv file and change `on_press` to `on_release`.

```
root.manager.get_screen("screen1").ids["input1"].focus
```

This line can be different by using object property in screen1, for example. Or if you cannot use the `on_release` method, maybe use clock to schedule a focus in some amount of time, and if the touch is still down, reschedule it.
But here is the quick fix.

```
<Menu2>:
    name: "screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Entrada"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "screen1"
                root.manager.get_screen("screen1").ids["input1"].focus = True
```